# Should I use "the" for proper names?

Tags: definite-article

There is this news channel I am introducing in a scenario that I describe.

> In the first scenario, suppose that **the** news channel PBC advertises
>   the p.

Is "the" required before "news channel PBC"?

Comment: You ask about proper names, but you are putting the article before words that are not capitalized, and therefore not proper nouns.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal rule about using an article (**a** or **the**) in front of the name of a broadcaster.

Some broadcasters are always introduced with **the**. It's **the BBC** and **the SABC** (South African Broadcasting Corporation).

The US channels on the other hand are usually referred to in my experience simply as **NBC**, **ABC** and **CBS** unless their full names are spelled out, when **the** precedes them.

**NBC** advises people to go to **NBC News**, not *the NBC News*.

While I'm not clear as to exactly what you mean by *advertises the p*, the answer to your question is that it depends - both on the channel's usage and on popular usage.

Comment: Several other proper nouns which take "the": the USSR, the Wirral, the Isle of Mull, the Eiffel Tower.

Answer (score 1):

> In the first scenario, suppose that the *news channel* PBC advertises the p.

Since "news channel" is not capitalized, I read this as:

> In the first scenario, suppose that **the news channel** (that is named) PBC advertises the p.

In such case, use *the*, since *news channel* is not a proper noun.

However, if the broadcaster was named "News Channel PBC", then no article is used.

> In the first scenario, suppose that **News Channel PBC** advertises the p.